# A simple way to make original source code, imported into svn, a working copy?

Tags: svn

Is there a simple way of putting source code into a repository and then making the original source code a working copy without having to delete it and then check it out again?

Comment: that's what `svn add` followed by `svn commit` does by default, isn't it? I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're talking about the initial `import` of a new project, right?  If so, the answer as far as I can tell is, no.  [Here's another post that covers the same thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2377785/svn-import-doesnt-create-svn-folder), and they come to the same conclusion, with a few suggested workarounds.

Comment: Thanks, I will try the suggested workaround in the above-referenced post, and try Memming's suggesting.